# Convert Unix Timestamp in Long original Timestamp value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, meteor

A unix timestamp was stored into the database (mongodb) as `NumberLong(1385297660000000000)`. When retrieving the timestamp, Chrome's developer console shows it as:

```
timestamp: Object
    _bsontype: "Long"
        high_: 322539745
        low_: -2018573312
```

How do I retrieve the original unix timestamp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract NumberLong data from Mongodb using Node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078207/how-to-extract-numberlong-data-from-mongodb-using-node-js)

Comment: @raina77ow The situation is different from mongodb as meteor uses its own _id objects.

Comment: Nyxynyx are these inserted from another non meteor app?

Comment: @Tarang: These are inserted into mongodb from Python. What is a good way to convert the Long object to unix timestamp?

Comment: I just posted one answer, but another idea occurs to me: MongoDB experts, is it possible to retrieve `"NumberLong(1385297660000000000)"` from the database as a strong? If so, the answer is a one-liner: `Math.round(parseInt("NumberLong(1385297660000000000)".match(/(\d+)/)[0]) / 1000000000)` for Unix timestamp, or `new Date(parseInt("NumberLong(1385297660000000000)".match(/(\d+)/)[0]) / 1000000)` for a JavaScript Date object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this quick way too:

```
longToDate = function(longValue) {
    var high = longValue._bsontype.high_;
    var low = longValue._bsontype.low_;
    return new Date(((high >>> 0) * Math.pow(16,8) + (low >>> 0))/Math.pow(10,6))
}
```

Then just use it e.g with your `timestamp`

```
longToDate(timestamp)
=> Sun, 24 Nov 2013 12:54:18 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

It feels like overkill, but this works:

1. Go get the [Long.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/Long.js) library
2. Put the library's `Long.min.js` into your Meteor project's `/lib` folder so that the Long object is available to both client and server (if required; otherwise put it in `/client/lib` or `/server/lib` as appropriate)
3. Per the [docs](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?http://github.com/dcodeIO/Long.js/master/docs/Long.html), use the following code; works even client-side:

(see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/byk33/2/))

```
var Long, value, unixTimestamp, jsTimestamp, date;
Long = dcodeIO.Long;
value = new Long(-2018573312, 322539745).toNumber();
// 1385297658711573500, almost the original 1385297660000000000

// Unix timestamps are in seconds, so lop off the last 9 digits
unixTimestamp = Math.round(value / 1000000000);
// 1385297659

// JavaScript timestamps are in milliseconds, so lop off the last 6 digits
jsTimestamp = Math.round(value / 1000000);
// 1385297658712

// Create Date object (if desired)
date = new Date(jsTimestamp);
// Sun Nov 24 2013 07:54:18 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

So if you really want the Unix timestamp, see the `unixTimestamp` variable above; or I'm assuming you probably would prefer a JavaScript `Date()` object, in which case use the `date` variable above. All you need to do is get your timestamp object's low and high values into where I put `-2018573312` and `322539745` in this code. Note that neither timestamp is exactly equal to the original 138529766 Unix timestamp; some precision is lost going into and out of the Long number type.

Comment: forgive me but if you want seconds and you get JS milliseconds, shouldn't you divide by 1000 not 1000000?

Comment: If you're trying to convert between a JS timestamp and a Unix timestamp, yes, divide or multiply by 1000. In the example above though the `value` variable is neither, but rather a much-longer integer. Its value is in the comment on line 4, and the subsequent comments show you the resulting values of `unixTimestamp`, `jsTimestamp` and `date`. The value of `value` never changes. Try the fiddle (link just above the example code) and you can see it in action.